# Trying to upgrade PT Fieldpack in EE 2.7.2

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

I upgraded from EE2.5.2 to EE2.7.2. I had the old individual P&T Dive Bar fields installed. I'm trying to upgrade to the new Field pack as per the instructions, but I can't access the Add-ons > Fieldtypes screen due to the following error:

> Fatal error: Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /var/www/vhosts/snip/subdomains/stage/system/expressionengine/third_party/pt_field_pack/pt_fieldtype.php on line 148

How can I bypass / fix this error so I can install the new fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could arguably be a duplicate of [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/13477/22), but it's a bit different because you're asking how to silence the error so you can finish the update per the [P&T docs](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/installation.html#updating-from-the-old-dive-bar-fieldtypes).

I just ran into this today myself and had the same question! The solution is courtesy of [this answer.](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13498/22)

Open up **pt_fieldtype.php** and below the constructor (around line 29) add:

```
public function display_field($data)
{
    // This placeholder function will prevent the PHP error
}
```

This will prevent the error and allow you to get on with the upgrade.

---

**OR** as Andris pointed out below, you can simply delete the old pt_fieldtype files and the error will go away so that you'll be able to install the new field pack.

Comment: Also you could just delete the old fieldtype folders, but some people might feel reluctant about that.

Comment: Thanks, @Andris. I totally thought that deleting the files of an _installed_ fieldtype would result in a missing fieldtype error in the control panel, but I see that it doesn't. I updated my answer.

Comment: FWIW, just deleting the old folders did not fix this problem for me. It did exactly what you assumed and just gave me a missing filetype error. Also critically, this thread (unlike the original one you credit) includes WHERE you're supposed to put this information, so thanks very much.

Comment: This allowed me to load the fieldtypes page. However, now when I install the switch, pill and list fieldtypes (in the modern Field Pack, not old P&T Field Pack) I get this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xcvvmc4bmg520y/Screenshot%202013-11-26%2017.14.52.png

Comment: @jthomas, I think it would be better if you post this issue as a new question (easier to tackle that way than via comments).